# Determining which vehicle Rob wants to buy

Tags: c#

> Rob is looking to buy a used pickup truck. He will spend a maximum of
>   $10,000 but would like to spend as little as possible. He will spend
>   up to $3000 for a 2000 or older model, $5000 for a 2001-05 model,
>   $7000 for a 2006-09 model, $9000 for a 2010 or newer model. Rob will
>   not buy a red truck but he will pay 20% more for a white truck.
>
> Given the information above and using C# or VB.net, write a function
>   using nested if/else statements that receives the following variables:
>
> ```
> d_Price decimal
>
> s_Color string
>
> i_Year integer
> ```
>
> ...and returns a `Boolean` value to determine whether a truck is one Rob
>   wants to buy.

I don't think is a good approach. How can this be improved?

```
 //Function to decide if the car is what Rob wants
static bool Rob_Wants(decimal d_Price, string s_Color, int i_Year)
{
    decimal [] max_array = {3000, 5000, 7000, 9000};  //max prices

    //if/else to check the condition
    if (s_Color == "Red" || d_Price>10000)
 return false;
    else if (s_Color == "White")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < max_array.Length; i++)
            max_array[i] = max_array[i]+((max_array[i] * 20) / 100);
    }
    if (d_Price <= max_array[0] && i_Year >= 2000)
        return true;
    else if (d_Price <= max_array[1] && i_Year >= 2001)
        return true;
    else if (d_Price <= max_array[2] && i_Year >= 2006)
        return true;
    else if (d_Price <= max_array[3] && i_Year >= 2010)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: This does't use any nested statements.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> ```
> decimal [] max_array = {3000, 5000, 7000, 9000};  //max prices
> ```

Let's try something:

```
int[] maxPrices = {3000, 5000, 7000, 9000};
```

Or even:

```
var maxPrices = new[] {3000, 5000, 7000, 9000};
```

The cutoff prices in the problem statement are all integers, so you don't need to bother with a `decimal` and floating-point errors here. And since you're using an array initializer to initialize a local variable with a handful of integers, the type of `maxPrices` is *obviously* `int[]`.

Notice also, that you stop needing the comments when the code can speak for itself: the informative and useful part of `max_array` is `max` - the rest of the useful meaning is hidden in a comment. Seeing `// max prices` next to a variable declaration tells me one thing: that this comment wouldn't need to be there if the variable was called `maxPrices` (notice `camelCase`).

[Convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx) for locals and parameters, is `camelCase`. Your code suffers from a severe Notationis Hungarianum - symptoms being that `d_` for "decimal", that `s_` for "string" and that `i_` for "integer". [Don't do that. Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111972/1188513):

> [*vUsing adjHungarian nnotation vmakes nreading ncode adjdifficult.*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/112080/1188513)

---

> *write a function using nested if/else statements*

Your function is structured like this:

- if
- else if

  - for
- if
- else if
- else if
- else if
- else

I see no nested `if` conditions. And you know what? That's awesome: nested ifs are usually not pretty, you'd normally want to avoid resorting to them.

Nested conditions would look like this:

- if

  - if

    - if
    - else
  - else if

    - if
    - else
  - else
- else

If doing that exercise should teach you one thing, it's to recognize that shape in your code. That shape has a name: it's [*arrow code*](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/), and it's usually not the code you want to be maintaining.

So, what then?

---

He will spend:

> - up to $3000 for a 2000 or older model
> - up to $5000 for a 2001-05 model
> - up to $7000 for a 2006-09 model
> - up to $9000 for a 2010 or newer model

Also, he:

> - will not buy a red truck
> - will pay 20% more for a white truck
> - will pay no more than $10,000

I think I'd use the built-in `Color` enum, just because it's there and appropriate for this.

I'd first eliminate the red truck, and return early:

```
if (color == Color.Red || price > 10000) { return false; }
```

And your code does exactly that. Well done!

Now the fun part. You went with arrays, and a `if..else if` construct. The problem is that when you read the code you can't help but notice the `[0]`, the `[1]`, the `[2]` and the `[3]` one under the other, all in order.

If I could *map a year to the maximum price I'm willing to pay for*, my life would be much simpler!

```
var maxPrices = new Dictionary<int,int> 
{
    { 2000, 3000 },
    { 2005, 5000 },
    { 2009, 7000 },
    { 9999, 9000 },
};
```

Then we can iterate the dictionary entries, return `true` and break out when the parameters compare favorably against the `Key` (year) and the `Value` (maximum price)

```
var result = false;
foreach(yearPrice in maxPrices.OrderBy(item => item.Key)) // note: item.Key is the year
{
    var maxPrice = yearPrice.Value;
    if (color == Color.White) 
    { 
        maxPrice *= 1.2; 
    }

    if (year <= yearPrice.Key && price <= maxPrice)
    {
        result = true;
        break;
    }
}
return result;
```

I don't understand the requirement for nested `if` statements. Specs usually tell you *what* to do, not *how* to do it. And imposing nested constructs (or anything really) sounds like some kind of "coding game" - however if you want to be writing professional code, that isn't the kind of code you want to be writing. Or rather, *maintaining*.

Comment: Wow, I learned more from your comment than a semester of school :) thank you a lot

Comment: @david my pleasure - note that an unsaid takeaway here, is that code gets much simpler when it's separated from the *data*.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is wrong: it rejects any car that is older than year 2000.

The `max_array` isn't providing any benefit to you.  All it does is make the code more cryptic, with `max_array[0]`, etc.  It would be better to write the code in a way that more closely associates the each price limit with its corresponding age.

The spec does not specify whether the color will start with an uppercase or lowercase letter.  I would normalize it to lowercase just in case.

Dropping braces is a dangerous software engineering practice.  If you really want to omit braces, [put the statement on the same line](//programmers.stackexchange.com/a/16530/51698) to help prevent coding accidents.

Here is a function that conforms to the spec:

```
static bool Rob_Wants(decimal d_Price, string s_Color, int i_Year)
{
    if (d_Price > 10000 || s_Color.ToLower() == "red")
    {
        return false;    // over budget or wrong color
    }
    else
    {
        decimal colorPremium = (s_Color.ToLower() == "white") ? 1.2m : 1.0m;

        if      (i_Year <= 2000) return d_Price <= colorPremium * 3000;
        else if (i_Year <= 2005) return d_Price <= colorPremium * 5000;
        else if (i_Year <= 2009) return d_Price <= colorPremium * 7000;
        else                     return d_Price <= colorPremium * 9000;
    }
}
```

---

I'm not at all a fan of the onerous Hungarian prefixes `d_`, `s_`, and `i_` in the spec, and recommend dropping them altogether.

You have wisely chosen to ignore the *nested if/else statements* part of the problem statement.  Personally, I would ignore that part of the spec too.  In fact, I would prefer using a ternary conditional and a switch instead.

The underscore in the function name is unconventional.

With those considerations, I would further rewrite the code:

```
static bool RobWants(decimal price, string color, int year)
{
    if (price > 10000) return false;              // Over budget
    decimal maxPrice = (year <= 2000) ? 3000 :
                       (year <= 2005) ? 5000 :
                       (year <= 2009) ? 7000 :
                                        9000;
    switch (color.ToLower())
    {
    case "red":
        return false;
    case "white":
        return price <= 1.2m * maxPrice;
    default:
        return price <= maxPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: [`String.Equals(String, String, StringComparison)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks(v=vs.110).aspx) + [`StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx) >>>>>>>>>>>>>>  [`String.ToLower()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78f86at(v=vs.110).aspx). Equals with a comparison is so much more expressive and precise than lowering before comparing.

Comment: @Johnbot In the general case, you're right that `String.ToLower()` is not a good way to do case-insensitive comparisons. However, here we are looking for fixed strings. Is there any case where this fails?

Comment: "WHITE".ToLower()=="white" in the Turkish locale

Comment: @Johnbot I wouldn't consider that to be a failure, though.